# Preserve animating UIView property after removing animations, but without using a class variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation

What's the right way to preserve an animating UIView property after removing the animations?

Specifically, the goal is to animate a 10-second progress bar.

If the user stops after 5 seconds, the progress bar should remain at 5 seconds. Instead it jumps to 10 seconds, the final value, once the animations are removed.

The only solution so far is use a class variable, but it seems hacky and one less variable to track would be ideal. Is this possible without a class variable?

We tried using the value from the `presentationLayer` as indicated below, but that also failed.

```
private func animateProgressBar(recording: Bool) {
    // Stop animation if not recording
    if (!recording) {
        print("Stopped recording")
        progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        return
    }

    // If here, animate progress bar
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(VideoDur, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.progressBarWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { finished in
            if (finished) {
                self.endRecording()
            } else {
                self.progressBarWidthConstraint.constant = self.progressBar.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame.width
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what finally worked. The key is reading `progressBar.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame.width`.

```
    if (!recording) {
        print("Stopped progress bar")
        progressBarWidthConstraint.constant = progressBar.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame.width
        progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might just go with the variable personally.  If you really hate that though, I might just pause the animation, rather than remove it.

```
progressBar.layer.speed = 0;
progressBar.layer.timeOffset = mediaTimeForLayer;
```

Comment: Is there any downside to merely pausing the animation? This seems much cleaner!

Comment: Also why is `timeOffset` needed?

Comment: Only downside I can think of is that you will have an animation floating around in memory.  I doubt there would be too much overhead though.  You might not need timeOffset - if you are never going to resume the animation again you won't need to track offsets.  If you are going to resume, then you will want to track how long you have been paused (currentMediaTime-timeOffset) and set that as your new beginTime.

Comment: Hmmm, replacing `progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()` with `rogressBar.layer.speed = 0` causes the progress bar to vanish. Suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html has some code that shows pausing and resuming.  Maybe offset is needed after all?

Comment: The docs seem to suggest the offset is needed for resuming, but will try anyway and report back ... thanks!

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. Also printing `progressBarWidthConstraint.constant` right after pausing shows 320 on an iPhone 5S, so it seems like setting the speed to 0 is somehow also finishing the animation ...